# Is it possible to start a task in parallel while another task is running from SBT console?

Tags: sbt

My scenario is the following:

I am running a jetty server from within sbt. While it is running, without stopping it, I'd also like to run another command.

Is this possible without running two instances of sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the new (as of sbt 1) `bgRun` command when running jetty. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2936

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: ...Oh. It can only run an application's default main class as a background job? What about using it to run a task?

Comment: You'll probably need to create a `bgJettyRun` task and use `bgJobService` and its `runInBackground`.

See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2936/files#diff-6373e7f7122325e753b75fe1cc76ff5fR844

Answer (score 1):

Try the `all` command, whose argument commands will be run in parallel.

So something like `all jettyStart otherCommand`.

Comment: Rather than start them in parallel, I'd like to do something along the lines of `jetty:start`, then wait a variable amount of time, run a command, wait again, run a command... Etc

Comment: @GibberlingLard I added an alternative answer.